# Python regex to extract a word which has + symbol

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

We have text as

```
"Google and Bert+Amazon+Alexa'
```

The expected output is when we pass a search text as Google and Bert then the output should be "Google and Bert" and it should not match when the input search word is Google. Need to match to the complete text which can be either before or in between or after symbol "+"

```
pattern = r'(?:^|\+)' + 'Amazon' + '(?:$|\+)' 
re.search(pattern, "Google and Bert+Amazon+Alexa").group()

Output is: +Amazon+ but the expected output is Amazon
```

Comment: If you just check if a string exists in between plus symbols print the search string if `re.search` succeeds. Note you may want to `re.escape(search_phrase)`. Of course, you may use `pattern = r'(?:^|\+)(' + 'Amazon' + ')(?:$|\+)'` and then `re.search(pattern, "Google and Bert+Amazon+Alexa").group(1)`, but it is probably bad logic.

Comment: `pattern = r'(?:^|\+)' + '(?P<grp>Amazon)' + '(?:$|\+)' `
`re.search(pattern, "Google and Bert+Amazon+Alexa").groups()[0]`

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a regex here in fact, just split the string with `+` and check if the `search` is in the resulting list:

```
s = "Google and Bert+Amazon+Alexa"
search = "Google and Bert"
if search in s.split('+'):
    print(search)
else:
    print("NO MATCH!")
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TZBkZU).

The result of `s.split('+')` will be `['Google and Bert', 'Amazon', 'Alexa']` and you will be searching for `Google and Bert` in this list, and returning/displaying the search phrase.

Regarding the regex approach, you may try something like `pattern = r'(?:^|\+)(' + re.escape(search) + ')(?:$|\+)'` and then `re.search(pattern, "Google and Bert+Amazon+Alexa").group(1)`, but it does not seem what you really need here.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `search`, Use at least a one capturing group and the captured text is returned like this:

```
import re
pattern = r'(?:^|\+)(Amazon)(?:$|\+)'
r = re.search(pattern, "Google and Bert+Amazon+Alexa")
print(r.groups())  #  ('Amazon',)
print(r.group(1))  #  'Amazon' not group(0)
```

In `match` and `search`: `group() and group(0)` will return the entire match, the captured groups are in `groups()`